# How are events generated in linux?

Tags: kernel

I am very new to Linux. 
I was actually wondering how the application gets different system events.

Eg : 1. A media player getting a button press notification
     2. Battery charge low event

I would love to know the complete sequence behind this.  I searched a lot but didn't get expected results.

Comment: As far as GUI is concerned, I think GTK window system takes care of this. See https://developer.gnome.org/platform-overview/stable/tour-events.html.en. This describes about actions sent for apps using GTK

Answer (score 0):

One of many answers to your question is [dbus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/).

Comment: Dbus I guess is for propagating events for interested parties
But how theses events are generated in a form suitable for linux system

Comment: Well, I think you interested in low level events, those generated by kernel. One example is a module monitoring a hardware. When there is an [interrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8259) from hardware, the module puts data in '/proc', for example, and then a daemon treat such data: acpid, for example. This topic is for long discussion.